# MySQL - How to get the string next after to a symbol?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

For Example: word_word_@_word_word

i want to replace third word from left after the @_ by someother word, i dont know the exact string from the database. So how can i write sql query for this.

Comment: removed incompatible SQL-Server tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `replace`:

```
select SELECT REPLACE('word_word_@_word_word', '@_word', '@_otherword');
```

Comment: i dont know the exact word/sentence and only i knew is @ symbol from the sentence, so how can i write query for this

Comment: @user you should clarify your question. also add some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Use Stuff function

---

```
 Declare @String varchar(200)='word_word_@_word_word'
    SELECT @String AS GivenString,STUFF(@String,(CHARINDEX('@_',@String)+2),0,'Otherword'+'_') AS Otherword_Column
```

OutPut

```
GivenString              Otherword_Column
------------------------------------------------------
word_word_@_word_word   word_word_@_Otherword_word_word
```